# Scraping a webpage with C# and HTMLAgility

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, data-mining

I have read that `HTMLAgility 1.4` is a great solution to scraping a webpage. Being a new programmer I am hoping I could get some input on this project.
I am doing this as a `C#` application form. The page I am working with is fairly straight forward.  The information I need is stuck between just 2 tags `<table class="data">` and `</table>`.

My goal is to pull the data for `Part-Num`, `Manu-Number`, `Description`, `Manu-Country`, `Last Modified`, `Last Modified By`, out of the page and send the data to a `SQL` table.

One twist is that there is also a small `PNG` picture that also need to be grabbed from the `src="/partcode/number`.

I do not have any completed code that woks. I thought this bit of code would tell me if I am heading in the right direction. Even stepping into the debug I can’t see that it does anything. Could someone possibly point me in the right direction on this. The more detailed the better since it is apparent I have a lot to learn.

Thank you I would really appreciate it.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Xml;

namespace Stats
{
    class PartParser
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://localhost");
            //My understanding this reads the entire page in?
            var tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
            // I assume that this sets up the search for words containing table
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

The web code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Part Number Database: Item Record</title>
        <table class="data">
            <tr><td>Part-Num</td><td width="50"></td><td>
            <img src="/partcode/number/072140" alt="072140"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Manu-Number</td><td width="50"></td><td>
            <img src="/partcode/manu/00721408" alt="00721408" /></td></tr>    
            <tr><td>Description</td><td></td><td>Widget 3.5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Manu-Country</td><td></td><td>United States</td></tr>    
            <tr><td>Last Modified</td><td></td><td>26 Jan 2009,  8:08 PM</td></tr>    
            <tr><td>Last Modified By</td><td></td><td>Manu</td></tr>
        </table>
    <head/>
</html>
```

Comment: See my answer if you want a working code using the HTML code you provided.

Answer (score 6):

The beginning part is off:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("http://localhost");
```

`LoadHtml(html)` loads an html string into the document, I think you want something like this instead:

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc  = htmlWeb.Load("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

A working code, according to the HTML source you provided. It can be factorized, and I'm not checking for *null* values (in `rows`, `cells`, and each value inside the `case`). If you have the page in *127.0.0.1*, that will work. Just paste it inside the `Main` method of a *Console Application* and try to understand it.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://127.0.0.1");    

var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='data']/tr");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var cells = row.SelectNodes("./td");
    string title = cells[0].InnerText;
    var valueRow = cells[2];
    switch (title)
    {
        case "Part-Num":
            string partNum = valueRow.SelectSingleNode("./img[@alt]").Attributes["alt"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Part-Num:\t" + partNum);
            break;
        case "Manu-Number":
            string manuNumber = valueRow.SelectSingleNode("./img[@alt]").Attributes["alt"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Manu-Num:\t" + manuNumber);
            break;
        case "Description":
            string description = valueRow.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Description:\t" + description);
            break;
        case "Manu-Country":
            string manuCountry = valueRow.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Manu-Country:\t" + manuCountry);
            break;
        case "Last Modified":
            string lastModified = valueRow.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Last Modified:\t" + lastModified);
            break;
        case "Last Modified By":
            string lastModifiedBy = valueRow.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Last Modified By:\t" + lastModifiedBy);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this example, it has taught me a little more on using html agility.  If your interested in a challenge I have another page I am working on getting data from that doesn't have a typical layout. I would love to see how you would handle the situation.

Comment: @JRB Well, I suggest you trying it by yourself first, and if you have problems making it work, post it as a question and what you tried to do, and we will try to help you.