# Get source code from loaded page from browsers in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, opera, mozilla

How can  read source code from loaded page in browsers? Html-code(page) after loading save in disk or where? How get this code from C# program, dont request from C# to url?

Comment: [A similar questions was asked here & will get you started!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320231/scraping-a-webpage-with-c-sharp-and-htmlagility) There is referral to the HTML Agility Pack, it's a super simple NuGet Package in Visual Studio, be sure to check it out! Afterwards you can create a text file by using the `System.IO` namespace, [explained here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Let me know if that works out for you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML Agility is good for scraping the website.

While there is another tool PHANTUMJS

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)