# How to capture web page certain field value using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, capture

I would like to capture the label value of the web page.
For example, the web page will be opened everyday once and the value of the label id="lblTest" can be captured automatically without manual record.

May i know how can I do this by using C# language and ASP.net? The web page doesn't has any API for me to retrieve the data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping a webpage with C# and HTMLAgility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320231/scraping-a-webpage-with-c-sharp-and-htmlagility)

Comment: are you using webforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Agility Pack.

[Here](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public string GetLabelValue(string url)
{            
    // download your web page content
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string downloadString = client.DownloadString(url);

    // regular expression
    var pattern = @"<label.+id=""lblTest"".{0,}>(.+)</label>";
    var match = Regex.Match(downloadString, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // getting the label value
    var labelValue = match.Groups[1].Value;

    return labelValue;
}
```

Comment: <table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="GridView1">
  <tr>
   <td align="left" width="90">ASN</td><td align="left" width="61">0.6852    </td><td align="left" width="70">5.00      </td><td align="left" width="67">-         </td>
  </tr><tr>
    </table>




Hi, this is the downloadString which I had been successfully capture. But how do i capture each value in the table since it is in GridView format and contain different column and row.