# How can i import/ check code from a webstite in my code?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, web-crawler

For example, i want to check if a product value from a certain web store is in one price range or another price range, how can i import the code from that web store? I saw a post talking about using Ajax requests to the server, but i can't acces this web store server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320231/scraping-a-webpage-with-c-sharp-and-htmlagility

Comment: Yes! TYSM!!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping a webpage with C# and HTMLAgility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320231/scraping-a-webpage-with-c-sharp-and-htmlagility)